# Organizing numerous labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to make a map of Paris and downloaded data from OSM that I'm currently organizing with QGIS.

The issue is I'd like to display all street names as labels yet many streets are rather small so labels are overlaying.

I need the labels to be "parallel" to the street (hence the corresponding label feature to be turned on) yet be able to move them around easily **keeping them parallel** which I'm currently unable to do.

When I move the label, it becomes horizontal instead of staying parallel to the street (see pictures bellow).

I know I can still turn them manually to get them where I want but considering it concernes thousands of streets I'd rather find a more suited tool to do so as efficiently as possible.

[image: Picture before moving labels]

[image: Picture after moving labels]

------- edit ---------

I tried using ARCGIS PRO and its labeling motor works great and solved all my issues !

Hugo